# Syntax Error when writing triple query

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I am writing the following query:

```
select object_id from sys.columns  
where name in ('TCP_Port_Export','TCP_Port_Import')
order by 1 desc
```

and getting the result as :

object_id

1322342229
1322342229
1306136094
1306136094
284905178
284905178

Then I am mixing this query to produce as :

```
select name from sys.tables where object_id in (select object_id from sys.columns  
where name in ('TCP_Port_Export','TCP_Port_Import'))
```

I am getting the result as : 
name

IB_Formats_BACKUP
IB_Formats
IB_Formats_Archive

But after I combine this query to form :

```
select * from (select name from sys.tables where object_id in (select object_id from sys.columns  
where name in ('TCP_Port_Export','TCP_Port_Import')))
```

I get the following error :

Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Can someone please help ?

Comment: The first `select *` seems to be redundant. Is that the actual query?

Answer (score 0):

You need to alias the query before you can do a `SELECT` from it. So you need to change it to:

```
select * from 
(select name from sys.tables 
 where object_id in 
 (select object_id from sys.columns  
  where name in ('TCP_Port_Export','TCP_Port_Import'))) as s
```

However, this will return the same result as just running the middle and innermost query, so please clarify why you need the top query.

Comment: The output from the second query i.e. IB_Formats_BACKUP
IB_Formats
IB_Formats_Archive are the table names. So I want the contents of the table, that is the reason why I am using 
    "select * from "
Can you please advise ?

Comment: It wont work like that. If you want to select from the tables you will need to use dynamic SQL. Please try to read up on dynamic SQL.

Comment: Is there any other which I can use ?

Comment: Not if you are using the query in your question. The table names are returned simply as strings not as any reference to database objects.